# Java Eclipse SWT OSX bug

Tags: eclipse, swt, osx-mountain-lion

So I researched a lot about this problem and haven't found anything useful for me yet.

It is mainly about this bug with:

```
[Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
```

Which seems to be related to a bug Eclipse know themselves.

I have tried running Eclipse Indigo, Eclipse 4.2.1 and Eclipse 4.3 with the same result. I tried starting the Eclipse on the second thread as suggested by somewhere "-XStartThreadSecond"<--- something like that, but Eclipse dont recognize that anymore it seems. So maybe someone found a solution to this after so long time?

I am running OSX Mountain Lion, JRE 6, above Eclipse's and I also tried making JRE 7 work in my Eclipse, but the JRE 7 VM dont exist in the folder it should be(I Haven't installed anywhere else).

EDIT:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=212617

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/809088/

Comment: Just edited my original post.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I was using JFreeChart, however none of the solutions worked. Every time I tried to run java application that created a JFrame it crashed on a Mac.

However, I had realized that I have had included all libraries that came with JFreeChart in the Project build path. If you have the same problem, check your library under:
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

All you need are: jcommon-1.0.17.jar, and jfreechart-1.014.jar

If you are not using JFreeChart, still check your build path if you are using some conflicting libraries.

Cheers!

Comment: I wasn't using conflicting libraries. I searched a long time for a solution for this problem, but I couldn't resolve it. It was a long time ago so I don't quite remember it, but I realised it was a bug in Eclipse related to the Java versions 1.6-1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using JFreeChart with Eclipse on OSX. It seems adding only jcommon-1.0.17.jar and jfreechart-1.014.jar into your JAR reference path instead of the whole list of libraries is the solution.

Thanks