# SWT Timeout on OSX, Application hangs

Tags: java, macos, swt

since i installed the OSX Java Update (2013-004, updates JRE to 1.6.0_51) my rcp will not start anymore. Started from console, i get a msg like this:

```
[Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
[Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeput for SWT to 0.100000
```

splash screen of my app appears, but thats all. i already read the posts:

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951883/java-swt-awt-eclipse-mac-osx-java-cocoa-compatibilitymode-enabled)

[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690219/gwt-osx-swt-issues)

[Post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621882/java-eclipse-swt-osx-bug)

but none of the solutions proposed there worked for me (neither secondthread ini-file solution).

I'm using eclipse 3.7 as my eclipse target platform. Interesting thing here is, when i download eclipse 3.7.2 for osx, it starts up as expected. So imho there has to be a solution to this, only thing is, i currently can't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: addition: i also tried to downgrade to 1.6.0_43 but osx won't let me do that telling me that a newer version of java is installed, but i already deleted the plugin and all vms at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Comment: OS X will surely let you have Java 1.6, but it must originate from Apple. I have successfully done it.

Comment: from apple i only get the 1.6.0_51 afaik (all older downloads redirect to the 2013-004), is there a way to get/install older versions?

Comment: Ah, OK. You want a specific fix version of 1.6. I thought you had issues working with Java 6 instead of Java 7. I don't believe the change in the fix version will do you any good.

Comment: i knew there are a lot of security fixes in _51 and you should not downgrade, but at least that would be a workaround for my customers (using offline workstations) in the first place (using java 7 is not an alternative)

Comment: seems like i found a solution, adding the vmarg "-Djava.awt.headless=true" to my ini file let my application start again with an installed 1.6.0_51